# Little's Law to calculate threads in order to service client's requests.

Tags: queueing-theory

I am totally dummy in math so do't mind if my question is silly, but i need help. According to an [Article](http://venkateshcm.com/2014/05/How-To-Determine-Web-Applications-Thread-Poll-Size/) Little's Law can be used to determine number of threads required in the pool to effectively service client's requests.
I am confused that how to apply it in the following scenario?

Requests are arriving at a server at the rate of 10 Requests/second.
Each request takes 2 seconds to complete. How many threads are required?

L= λ*T -> 
L=10*2=20

20 threads are required. Is it correct? if not then please let me help.

Comment: It looks correct to me. If follows the formula in the article and the answer makes sense. If $10$ requests come in, $10$ threads start working on them. In the next second, the remaining $10$ threads start on the new $10$ incoming requests. A second later, the first $10$ threads are done and are available to handle the $10$ new incoming requests and so on.

Comment: But i am in doubt, because units of measurements are not consistent. rate is in per second whereas job completes in two seconds. Half of the job is completed in 1 second actually...